# Quadratic fields with moderately large fundamental units

Tags: nt.number-theory, analytic-number-theory, algebraic-number-theory, binary-quadratic-forms

Let $d > 1$ be a fundamental discriminant, and let $K_d = \mathbb{Q}(\sqrt{d})$. Denote by $\varepsilon_d$ the fundamental unit of $\mathcal{O}_{K_d}$, namely the smallest algebraic integer $\varepsilon_d = u_d + v_d \sqrt{d}$ with both $u_d, v_d > 0$ such that $u_d^2 - d v_d^2 = \pm 1$. What do we know about the counting function

$$\displaystyle \# \left\{d \leq X : d < \varepsilon_d < d^2 \right\}?$$

Note that we have the trivial lower bound $\varepsilon_d > \sqrt{d}$, and the upper bound $\varepsilon_d \ll \exp(\sqrt{d})$. Indeed, it is believed that for most $d$ the fundamental unit is of the same order of magnitude as the upper bound.

Comment: Just to quibble, you actually only have $\epsilon_d\ge(\sqrt{d-4}+\sqrt{d})/2$ as the trivial lower bound, which is achieved when $d=u^2+4$ is squarefree.